# additivity of trace with respect to short exact sequences

Tags: reference-request, abelian-categories, braided-tensor-categories, short-exact-sequences

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian rigid symmetric monoidal category over a field $K$. Assume that the endomorphism ring of the tensor unit in $\mathcal{C}$ is $K$.  If $X$ is an object in $\mathcal{C}$ and $f:X\to X$ is an endomorphism one can define the trace of $f$ as the composite
$$\textbf{1}\stackrel{coev_X}{\to} X\otimes X^*\stackrel{f\otimes 1}{\to} X\otimes X^*\stackrel{c_{X,X^*}}{\to} X^*\otimes X\stackrel{ev_X}{\to} \textbf{1}$$
I am looking for a reference to a proof of the following claim: Assume that we have a short exact sequence $$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and that $f:B\to B$ is an endomorphism. Assume moreover that $f(A)\subseteq A$, so that $f$ induces endomorphisms $g:A\to A$ and $h:C\to C$. Then
$$\text{Tr}(f) = \text{Tr}(g) + \text{Tr}(h).$$

Comment: This is a consequence of Proposition 4.7.5 in https://pages.uoregon.edu/vostrik/book/surv-205.pdf Unfortunately there is no proof..